# .erb templates in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have some ruby .erb templates for HTML files I need to use them in C# console application to generate HTML files . Ruby templates look like this . How do i do something like this with C# ? To replace values in a file stored on disk by passing it an object and creating a complete HTML file .

```
<html>
    <body>
    <h1>Languages details</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Language</th>
            <th>Family/Origin</th>
            <th>No. of speakers</th>
            <th>Region</th>
        </tr>
         <% @list_of_langauges.each do |item| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.name %></td>
            <td><%=item.family %></td>
            <td><%=item.users %></td>
            <td><%=item.region %></td>
        </tr><% end %>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [T4 text templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx).

Comment: @keyboardP T4 Text Templates worked for me . You could keep your answers and I can accept it .

Comment: related to "[ERB like library for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396506/erb-like-library-for-c-sharp)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `erb` but it sounds like you're looking for [T4 text templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb126445.aspx).

Comment: Yes that looks like what I need . Should I put html inside .tt file ? What function I have to execute to generate completed html file ?

Comment: Yes, you can then use `<#` and `#>` to denote your code. [See this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee844259.aspx) for an example.